# multivariable limits with three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1)Find $\lim_{E\ni(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}x^{yz}$, where $E=\{(x,y,z):x,y,z>0\}$

2)Find $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,1,0)}\dfrac{\sin(xyz)}{x^2+z^2}$

For(1), it seems to me that I should first try $\lim_{E\ni(x,y,z)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}yz\ln x$, but no matter what path I use, I'll always get the answer $0$. (The answer is that the limit does not exist, by the way.)

For (2), can I just simply ignore the $y\rightarrow1$? It seems rather....useless by itself. If I could change the limit to $\lim_{(x,z)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{\sin(xz)}{x^2+z^2}$, that would be way easier as I could just put $z=mx$ and say it does not exist. Is this rigorous?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1: Hint: $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x = 1$.

2: Yes. "$z=mx, y=1$" is a valid path passing through $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: 1. yes, but that seems to be the value that all the paths lead to!   2. Yes, that's valid, but can I just ignore the variable $y$ like that? I can't , could I?